What limitations do I have in Blazor Static server-side rendering (static SSR)?
I want to understand a bit better how the Blazor Static server-side rendering (static SSR) is working. In the official Microsoft repository, there aren't any examples.
I saw a few links about it:

Implementing and understanding a Blazor Static Server-Side Rendered Counter Page
Microsoft documentation

What it is not clear to me is how to create a full application using static SSR and what the benefits are. Also, in the coding point of view, what limitations do I have? I can use Blazor Components? Where can I find some example of applications written with Blazor Static SSR? Can I access an external SQL Server from the application using the Microsoft.Data.SQLServer and/or the DbContext of my application?
In the configuration point of view, how can I define a project for Blazor Static SSR?
Do I have to remove those line?
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents()
    .AddAuthenticationStateSerialization();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(BlazorApp3.Client._Imports).Assembly);

How can I be sure that the project is working in Static SSR and not using some other rendering?
If I have a project in Interactive mode, can I set a page to be rendered in Static SSR?
If in a ASP.NET Core application, I add
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

is this render the pages only with SSR?

I don't think setting  to static will make sense for the entire application. U should use it only for the pages  that don't require interactivity ( examples are the company’s history, about pages or website homepage). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-9.0#static-server-side-rendering-static-ssr
